# LaTeX cannot embed images located inside a folder

Tags: graphics, external-files

I have a few JPEG images inside a folder. I use the following code to embed images

```
\begin{figurehere}

  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{folder\test.jpg}
    \caption{Example \cite{visbin}}

\end{figurehere}
```

But LaTeX doesn't allow me to compile it. It says `Undefined control sequence <argument> folder\test`

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: It seems you're using the [`science` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scientificpaper), which provides the `figurehere` environment. It's advisable to always provide such information in your questions so that other users can help you easily without having to figure out what packages you're using first. (It didn't matter for this problem, but is generally really helpful.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't use backslashes recklessly. The standard directory separator should work fine on all platforms:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{folder/test.jpg}
%                                         ^^^^^
```

You can even omit the suffix `.jpg` to let the driver pick the best representation of the image (e.g. JPEG for PDF, and EPS for PS).

Answer (score 8):

An alternative would be to set the `\graphicspath` (provided by [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)) that LaTeX should use via

```
\graphicspath{{folder/}{otherfolder/}}
```

Also see the TeX FAQ entry on [Importing graphics from "somewhere else"](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-graphicspath).